# How can you play iTunes radio within an iOS app?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I currently have an iOS 8 app that plays music from a user's iTunes library on their device. I do this like so:

```
MPMediaItemCollection *musicItem = self.musicItem;
self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:musicItem];
[self.musicPlayer play];
```

I would like to add the ability to play a user's iTunes radio music as well, but there doesn't seem to be a media query for iTunes radio. Is there any way to play iTunes radio stations from within my own app?

I'm not bound to using MPMusicPlayerController, so if there is another way to do this I could use that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not entirely impossible, you'd have to use private `Radio` framework, so such an app won't be accepted into the App Store.

If you are still interested, you can try to figure out how to do it using [these headers](https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers/tree/57a9186dfb623a8018f2321bdd85abb32a3b0126/iOS8.1/PrivateFrameworks/Radio), but you will probably need to install something like [snoop-it](https://code.google.com/p/snoop-it/) on a jailbroken device to trace the method calls in the original `Music` application, so you can reimplement the functionality in your own app.